# How to update datetimepicker when a date is selected?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm working with xdsoft's datetimepicker : [See Docs](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) to allow user to select a booking date and time.

I have a table 'fechas' in a database to store information on dates that have bookings. For example, date 2020/04/28 has a booking for 7 pm.

In this particular datetimepicker, they have a function 'setOptions' which takes an array of 'options', which is very useful for storing the dates that are available and then call 'allowTimes' to pass the array of dates.

Currently, I am able to change the available hours but they show for the previously selected date rather than showing their respective dates.

When the user clicks on submit, the available hours show below the datetimepicker, however, what I would like to do is to update the hours that are available every time the user clicks on a new date.

Here is are the files I'm working with
**test.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="test-form" id="test-form" method="POST">
        <div id="test-container" style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:100px;">
            <p>Seleccione la fecha para verificar horarios</p>
            <input type="text" name="test_day" class="test_day" id="test_day" placeholder="15 / 08 / 2018">
            <input type="submit" id="test_submit" name="test_submit" value="Submit">
            <div id="test_response" name="test_response"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
<script src="datetimepicker/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</html>
```

**test.js**

```
//Logica para la validacion y base de datos

var horas_disponibles = [];

$('#test_submit').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var fecha = $('#test_day').val();
    var separados = fecha.split(" ");

    var btn = $("#test_submit").val();

    var respuesta = document.getElementById("test_response");

    if(fecha)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "test_fechas.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'fecha' : separados[0],
                'hora' : separados[1],
                'btn' : btn
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response)
                {
                    if(response == "db-error")
                    {
                        respuesta.innerHTML = "<p>Error al conectarse a la base de datos</p>";
                    }

                    else if (response == "emptyFields")
                    {
                        respuesta.innerHTML = "<p>Faltan parametros</p>";
                    }

                    else if (response == "allDatesAvailable")
                    {
                        respuesta.innerHTML = "<p>Todas las fechas disponibles</p>";
                    }
                    else {

                        var db_ans = response.split(",");
                        var horas_normales = ["19:00", "19:30", "20:00","20:30"]; // Data 1 - frente a este comparamos

                        for (var i =0; i < horas_normales.length; i++)
                        {
                            var esIgual = false;
                            for (var j = 0; j < db_ans.length & !esIgual; j++)
                            {
                                if(horas_normales[i] == db_ans[j])
                                {
                                    esIgual = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if(!esIgual)horas_disponibles.push(horas_normales[i]);
                        }

                        respuesta.innerHTML = "<p>Las horas disponibles son: " + horas_disponibles[0] + " " + horas_disponibles[1];

                    }

                }
                else {
                    respuesta.innerHTML = "<p>No hubo respuesta</p>";
                }
            }
        });
    }  


});


$('#test_day').datetimepicker({
    minDate: '-1970/01/01',
    disabledWeekDays: [0,1,3,5,6],
    onSelectDate: function(input, $input)
    {
        this.setOptions({
            allowTimes: horas_disponibles
        });
    }

});
```

**test_fechas.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
    require_once("includes/dbh.inc.php");
    require_once("includes/conexion.inc.php");

    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $hora = $_POST['hora'];
    $btn = $_POST['btn'];

    if (empty($fecha) || empty($hora))
    {
        echo "emptyFields";
        exit();
    }

    else {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM fechas where fecha=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);

        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql))
        {
            echo "db-error";
            exit();
        }
        else {

            $fecha = strtotime($fecha);
            $formattedDate = date('Y-m-d', $fecha);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $formattedDate);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
            {
                $horas_ocupadas = $row['horas'];
                echo $horas_ocupadas;
            }

            else{

                echo "allDatesAvailable";
                exit();

            }
        }

    }
}
else 
{
    header("Location: ../test.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like right after you determine the new list of available times:

```
respuesta.innerHTML = "<p>Las horas disponibles son: " + horas_disponibles[0] + " " + horas_disponibles[1];
```

you need to add this line to inject them back into the datetimepicker:

```
$('#test_day').datetimepicker('setOptions', {allowTimes: horas_disponibles });
```